# How we can hide splash screen in ionic app?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic4

There is anyway to hide or don't display splash screen in ionic app, and splash screen time in capacitor is fewer or in cordova is fewer, and How to reduce the time of splash screen in ionic app. Thanks (-:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a tweak for disabling the splash screen.
 In config.xml file:

```
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="0" />
```

You can further change its behavior with the following settings in config.xml file:

```
<preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="100" />
    <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="true" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
```

For more settings, please check the **splash screen documentation**: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen#configxml

To add a **custom animated splash screen**, follow this link: https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/generate-a-custom-spash-screen-and-icons-in-ionic/

Comment: this is how to disable splash screen in cordova, but he's using capacitor

Comment: The question asks about capacitor or Cordova.