# Change Splash Screen Programmatically in ionic 4

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-native

I have a challenge to change Splash dynamic. Server upload Image and I show as a splash. there are some points

1. show splash instead of default splash.
2. download image from URL and store in App or local Storage.
3. Hit to the server and store every time image.

Kindly help me to resolve this challenge.

I find the solution like download image. but how to store in ionic storage. Show Image instead of default splash.

Comment: You can create new `ViewController` to show it as a splash

Comment: Can you please explain it to me again in more detail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution. Like I use the "file" plugin to get "dataDirectory" path like "file:///data/user/0/com.ecomplanners.nawarco/files/" from the android device and same my downloaded file. and this path set in local storage.

If path exists then show this image like a splash instead of default splash.

Answer (score 0):

> First of all, you cannot change the default splash screen. You can
>   only change the background with splash.png in resources folder.

There are some tweaks for changing the time for which the default splash shows( like hide progress bar). Checkout this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58038655/10602679

If you want to show an image downloaded from server in splash screen, you will have to use  and set z-index of img with CSS in app.component.html .

Checkout this article: https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/generate-a-custom-spash-screen-and-icons-in-ionic/

Comment: I'm able to download the image shown before app.component data load and show after splash. how I set delay time splash in config.xml 0 splash, not show. but white screen appear how can I handle white screen now?

Comment: You can't make the white screen disappear because when you click the app icon, behind the scene, ionic app is loading in a WebView. What I recommend is that you should create your splash.png file with an attractive background. That way, you won't get white/blank screen for the first few seconds when app loads in WebView on device.

Comment: If this solution helped you, please mark it as an answer so that others can take help from it in the future. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, I'll add my answer.